# Materialize CSS nested Scrollspy not working: How to implement it?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, materialize

**Requested behaviour:**

I am creating an Angular app with two side-menus. The right side menu is the main menu. The left side menu is a submenu that displays the subchapters of the main chapters.

Since the content is displayed on one page/route, I would like to use two Materialize Scrollspys (or one Scrollspy for both menus if possible) to indicate the user's position on the page. Therefore, the scrollspy should highlight the current main chapter on the left side and the current subchapter on the right side.

**Current State**

I tried to implement this behavior by nesting two Materialize scrollspys. The Scrollspy is initialized correctly and highlights both menus.

**Issue**

However, the nested scrollspy is not working. It only highlights the outer Scrollspy and therfore only highlights the outer menu. The following image shows the missing highlight on the main menu (left side bar).

[image: Scrollspy does not highlight the nested menu if nested scrollspys are usded]

I created a stackblitz app to reproduce the issue: [StackBlitzApp](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-materialize-nested-scrollspys-issue?file=src/app/app.component.css)

You can find a more detailed issue discription and the full code in my GitHub repo: [GitHub Issue & Code](https://You%20can%20find%20a%20more%20detailed%20issue%20discription%20and%20the%20full%20code%20in%20my%20GitHub%20repo:)

**My Component.ts:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import M from 'materialize-css';

import { Observable, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  elem: HTMLElement;
  instance: any;

  elem2: HTMLElement;
  instance2: any;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.elem = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.scrollspy');
    this.instance = M.ScrollSpy.init(this.elem);

     this.elem2 = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.scrollspy2');
    this.instance2 = M.ScrollSpy.init(this.elem2);
  }
}
```

**My Component.hmtl:**

```html
<ul class="section table-of-contents left">
  <li><a href="#section1">section1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section2">section2 (Main Menu)</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section3">section3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="section table-of-contents right">
  <li><a href="#section21">section21 (Submenu)</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section22">section22 (Submenu)</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section23">section23 (Submenu)</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="section1" class="scrollspy outer-container">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
</div>

<!--Main chapter -->
<div id="section2" class=" outer-container">
<!-- 
  Add scrollspy as class to section 2 
  if scrollspy added in outer-container, inner menu not working
  
  if scrollspy not added, outer menu is not working correctly since not highlighting chapter 2

  if scrollspy2 is used for inner menus, similiar issues exist

-->
    <h1>Section 2 (Main Menu)</h1>
      <div id="section21" class="scrollspy inner-container">
        <h2>Section 21 (Submenu)</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="section22" class="scrollspy inner-container">
        <h2>Section 22 (Submenu)</h2>
    </div>
      <div id="section23" class="scrollspy inner-container">
        <h2>Section 23 (Submenu)</h2>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- Subchapters-->

<div id="section3" class="scrollspy outer-container">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
</div>
```

How can I fix that? Is there a way to use nested "Scrollspy"'s with MaterializeCSS? Or is there a better solution? Could you provide a code example?

Comment: Hmm. Never come across this. But you're not using scrollspy in the correct way. Is this intentional? According to the docs, each section needs an ID, triggered usually by a href that matches. I can't see any IDs on your markup? How would the framework know which option to highlight?

Comment: @SeanDoherty: That was not the issue. I added a StackBlitz template reproducing the issue to my initial question. I tried to reduce the html markup for this post a bit to much and added the IDs now